# How to set frame rate of flutter app running on linux

Tags: linux, flutter, dart

I am developing a flutter app for linux, the first time I compiled the code it gave me a warning that frame rate is set to 30 due to some reason which unfortunately I don't remember and I can't reproduce the warning.

And now the app runs at 30 fps and feel laggy. How to set the frame rate in code to at least 60 fps?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this package to set custom Hz and screen resolution - [flutter_displaymode](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_displaymode).

[Original link](https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/m5ro0j/flutter_locked_at_60fps_on_high_refresh_rate/)

Comment: That library seems to be only for Android...